# Erro de YogaNode

Tags: react-native

Constantemente, estou tendo o erro:

> Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! (Trying to add a 'ReactRawTextShadowNode' to a 'LayoutShadowNode')

Não entendi a lógica do erro, por isso não consegui corrigir.

Segue meu código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Tile, List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

class UserDetail extends Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, whatsapp, email, phone, location } = this.props.navigation.state.params;

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Tile
          imageSrc={{ uri: `https://buscafree.com.br/assets/img/items/${id}.jpg`}}
          featured
          title={title}
        />
        <List>
          {phone ? (<ListItem title="Telefone" rightTitle={phone} hideChevron />) : ''}
        </List>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default UserDetail;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre porque existe alguma informação "solta", ou seja, não está dentro de tags.

No meu caso é na linha `{phone ? (<ListItem title="Telefone" rightTitle={phone} hideChevron />) : ''}`

Quando `phone` existe, ele gera um `ListItem`, porém quando não existe, ele gera um espaço vazio (é onde está o erro). O correto é usar assim:

`{phone ? (<ListItem title="Telefone" rightTitle={phone} hideChevron />) : '<View></View>'}`